# How do I use "Salt water"?

Tags: the-sushi-spinnery

In the Market In can buy "Salt Water", "Sashimi Knife" and other "Power ups" that say that they can be applied to ingedients

[image: Screenshot of Salt Water]

I know how to apply "Amenity Gem" to vending machines and "Powdered Tea" to seats, how do I apply "Salt Water" to things?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - you apply the power up to the dish, the effect that the power up has on the dish depends on what ingredients are in the dish.

To apply the power up you need to select a dish in the "Dishes" part of the menu and the first screen will have a button that you can press to choose an item to apply to the dish.

[image: Screenshot of the Dish menu]

If you scroll down you can see the ingredients in a dish on the last page.

Comment: Note: This only powers up the "base" ingredient.  Later on, you can use multiple ingredients that you can power up, but you have to use the items on dishes where it is the base ingredient to affect other dishes that use it.